# Estimation of a particular sum

Tags: inequality

I need to estimate the expression of the form
 $$x^{1-\alpha} + y^{1-\alpha},$$
where $0< \alpha < 1, \; x > 0,\; y>0 $ given that $$|x-y|\leq \delta.$$ It is probably not at all complicated, but somehow I am stack. My goal is to obtain the estimation of the form $$x^{1-\alpha} + y^{1-\alpha} < K\delta.$$
So far I have tried the following obvious way: from $||x|-|y||< |x-y|<\delta$, assuming e.g. that $|x|< |y|$ we get $x^{1-\alpha} + y^{1-\alpha} < |x|+ |y| < \delta + 2|y|$.

Can anyone probably help me with that inequality? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Well there is no restriction on $y$ is there? I mean $y$ could be absolutely anything! So you last inequality cannot be bounded since $y$ can be as large as I want.

Comment: yes, you are right. I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

let      $ x-y=t\delta, ,t \le 1 ,f(x)=x^{1-\alpha} + (x-t\delta)^{1-\alpha}$ find $f_{max}$.

then you can find $ f_{max}$ and $ t  $ relation.